# Pagination example for greater than 2000 Records in AtTask API

Tags: java, pagination, attask

In AtTask API Calls,  How do I use Pagination when I need More than 2000 records to return?
For example, given the following off of the Developers Site of https://developers.attask.com/api-docs/#Basics I see the following

> Paginated Responses
>
> To override the default number of results and set the response to provide 200 results you would include the following in your query:
>
> `GET /attask/api/project/search?$$LIMIT=200`
>
> To ensure reliability and performance for other tenants in the system, the maximum allowed limit per query is 2000 objects. Attempting to specify a larger limit will result in an error.
>
> Therefore, it is recommended you consider using paginated responses for large datasets. To specify the first result that should be returned, the `$$FIRST` filter can be added. The following will return results 201-250 for a query.
>
> `GET /attask/api/project/search?$$FIRST=201&$$LIMIT=50`

What I'm not understanding is how to figure out how many I have in the first place.  If I am looking to download the hours in the system, how do I know how many times I have to call (is there a `count(*)`) or some method like that?  Am I simply going to get the first 2k, process, attempt to get the next 2k, and process if not empty? Rinse and repeat?

Answer (score 1):

Since the initial search will only pull 2000 results you will have to iterate and pull the next 2000 until there are no results left.

Comment: We can also check if the current response contains objects less than 2000 then stop to iterate. As its indicate that there is no more data.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the total count of items using a report call.  So in your example, to get the number of hour objects in the system (NOT the summed total hours), you could do the following:

```
/attask/api/HOUR/report?ID_AggFunc=count
```

Hope that helps!